# Can rollback transaction among multiple query in Mysql, rollback while one Update query update 0 rows?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to update and insert multiple Mysql query within a Rollback transaction from C# windows application. I expect rollback when at least one query fail to update rows due to its **condition become false**.

I heard roll back only happen when transaction failed due to sudden error.

```
private void btnCheckin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Dictionary<int, string> queryList = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        queryList.Add(0, "INSERT INTO `booked_room`(`bok_id`, `cat_id`, `rom_no`) VALUES (1,2,3)");
        queryList.Add(1, "UPDATE `room` SET `rom_stat`=1  WHERE `rom_stat`=0 AND `rom_no`=3");

if (rollbkUpdate(queryList))MessageBox.Show("Success");
else MessageBox.Show("Failed");

    }




public bool rollbkUpdate(Dictionary<int,string> query)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn= ConnString();
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            MySqlTransaction startTrans = conn.BeginTransaction();
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.Transaction = startTrans;
            int i = 0;            
            try
            {
                for (i = 0; i < query.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (query.ContainsKey(i))
                    {
                        comm.CommandText = query[i];
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
                    }
                }
                startTrans.Commit();
                if (i == query.Count) return true;
                else return false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                try
                {
                    startTrans.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: yes, you can ... you need to depend on `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` results - read doc what it returns

Comment: You mean i have to check if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() < 1){ startTrans.Rollback();}